# How do I set an element's height with Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a Polymer behavior that is supposed to take a selected element's width and set its height to that width on "ready" and when the window is resized. I've done the "get the width" part but setting the height does not work. Here's the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script>
  SquareBehavior = {
    properties: {
      victim: Object
    },
    listeners: {
      'resize': 'squareIt' // not working
    },
    squareIt: function() {
      this.victim = this.$$('.round');
      console.log(this.victim.offsetWidth); // this works fine
      // what do I add here?
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.squareIt(); //works
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you type: `this.victim.style.height = this.victim.offsetWidth`? Not sure if it's the "Polymer"-way but you could add the event listener like this: `window.addEventListener("resize", function() { squareIt(); }); `

Comment: Nope, tried this first. As far as the listener goes, I'd rather do it the "Polymer way". Plus it does not work either.

Comment: I don't understand how the accepted answer solves your question. It does not talk about resizing height. I thought that was your question.

Comment: @Srik, it does. He's telling me to use iron-resizable-behavior. I did it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iron-resizable-behavior.

https://github.com/polymerelements/iron-resizable-behavior

```
<html>
/*...*/
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-resizable-behavior/iron-resizable-behavior.html">
/*...*/

    Polymer({

        /*...*/

        listeners: {
            'iron-resize': "_resizeHandler"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to declare style property and set the reflect to attribute to true

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script>
  SquareBehavior = {
    properties: {
      victim: Object
      style: {
        type: String,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }
    },
    listeners: {
      'resize': 'squareIt' // not working
    },
    squareIt: function() {
      this.victim = this.$$('.round');
      console.log(this.victim.offsetWidth); // this works fine
      // what do I add here?
      this.style = "{height: " + this.victim.offsetWidth + " }"
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.squareIt(); //works
    }
  };
</script>
```